# Looking for a better OOP approach

Tags: python, django

I want to update a users balance. To do this currently I have to save the **Account** object,  consider the following view:

```
def refresh_balance(request):
    """
    Balance Refresh.

    The balance shown on every page is a cached balance for performance reasons.
    To get the real balance you need to re-save the account object which will refresh
    the cached value in the database.

    """
    page = request.GET['redirect']
    account = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
    account.save()
    message_user(
        request.user,
        "Account Balance Refreshed.")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(page)
```

In the model.py I have the following **Class Methods** that does the leg work:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.balance = self._balance()
        return super(Account, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def _balance(self):
        aggregates = self.transactions.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))
        sum = aggregates['sum']
        return D('0.00') if sum is None else sum
```

This to me look cumbersome, I'm re-saving to re-save (if that makes sense) and ideally I want to just call refresh() within any of my views, whenever I want. I'm no Django expert and need some advice on how to better handle this.

I have looked at **static methods** maybe?

```
def _balance(self):
        aggregates = self.transactions.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))
        sum = aggregates['sum']
        return D('0.00') if sum is None else sum

    @staticmethod
    def update_balance(model):
        model.balance = unsure here as I need 'self'?
```

Then just calling `Account.update_balance(Account)`?????

Any advice? 
PS this is not an open question, it's clear what I'm trying to do and what I'm after. Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you just create `refresh` object method (not static) in Account model, that will do needed actions and then just call `self.save()` from this `refresh` method?

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing you could do with a stored procedure on your database.

Comment: @Aya store procedure would be good, but I'm looking for a way at the moment within code and I don't want to lock myself to a DB at this stage.

Comment: Good idea @stalk, would this be ideal?

Comment: To my mind, it will be clear. Can't garantee, that it is ideal :D. I'll write this approach as an answer

Comment: Why don't you use a signal to recompute the balance only when a transaction is created ? (I assume transactions can only be created - never updated nor deleted, but even then you could use signals too)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: That might work, but it could also create a lot of problems when adding many transactions. I'd rather add a signal that just *clears* the the balance when a transaction is added, and computes it when fetched, if cleared. But I don't have the code for that. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: yeps, that's what I thought too after posting this suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stalk's answer is good but I prefer it when methods do one thing and one thing only.
As it is now, `.refresh()` takes care of two things. Computing balance and saving.
I would break it up even further by implementing the `.refresh()` method but in the view do this. (Also I would name it refresh_balance instead of refresh, refresh implies that we refresh the whole account).

```
account.refresh_balance()
account.save()
```

This makes it so that the logic for `.refresh_balance()` can change but the `.save()` would be left alone to do what it makes best. Save your model to the database.

This will also make your code less prone to bugs.
We'll also follow The Zen of Python by: "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: I like this answer, and yes a good approach to keep them separate like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to create custom model method, for example `refresh`:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    # ... some fields

    def refresh(self):
        # do needed stuff
        self.balance = self._balance()
        self.save()
```

And then just call it:

```
# ...
account = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
account.refresh()
```